# Two post destination in one script with form action tag blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is simple form :

```
<form id="contactform" method="POST" action="" >
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control"  id='first_name' name='first_name' > 
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg " name="form_subbmit">Send</button> 
</form>
```

And myscript for subbmit:

```
<script>


// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#contactform").submit(function( event ) {

 var $form = $( this );

 first_name=$form.find( "input[name='first_name']" ).val();


 $.post( "http://post1.com", { first_name: first_name  } );
 $.post( "http://post2.com", {first_name: first_name  } );

});
</script>
```

Now, if I put one of two post destination in action of form,all is fine. If take code like this,no submit at all.

How can I sent data to post destinations and take action filed of form to be blank ?

Tnx

Comment: Prevent default event of `form` first with `event.preventDefault()` at the very first line of `submit`

Comment: Tnx. JUst tell me,I put thet inisde function like this?   $( "#contactform").submit(function( event ) {  event.preventDefault();

Comment: Inside the function..

Comment: Get error : 500 Internal Server Error, just test with firebug

Comment: Internal server error means that's your server side error!!

Comment: Resolve server problem,sintax mistake :) now,all data is post,but there si next problem, data from post2.com,dont  insert into database. When put in action form post2.com,data insert successful ,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script>
   function submitWithPost(){
      var $form = $( this );

 first_name=$form.find( "input[name='first_name']" ).val();


 $.post( "http://post1.com", { first_name: first_name  } );
 $.post( "http://post2.com", {first_name: first_name  } );

   }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return submitWithPost();" >
```

Answer (score 0):

First put the event prevent default:

```
$("#contactform").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

On done you have to clean the input text field like this:

```
$.post( "http://post1.com", { first_name: first_name })
      .done(function(data) { 
         $form.find("input[name='first_name']").val('');
      });
```